# drush migrate-status command not found

Tags: drush

I've installed both version of drush using composer, and trying to list migration within my newer drup8 installation, in order to migrate an older drupal 7 website .. then I feel really stucked because I can't follow the next commands to execute ..

```
composer global require drush/drush:dev-master --> migrate-status not found
composer global require drush/drush:7.* --> won't work with drupal8
```

Any ideas or enlightment would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try 'composer global update' ? What message do you have ?

Comment: Finally found the solution .. 

1) Modules migrate_plus && migrate_upgrade have to be installed via their respective zips into modules folder, don't expect them to be directly within drush

2) Migrate_upgrade seems to work only with 8.0.dev version of drupal, not any beta, or 8.1.dev

3) This migrate upgrade does a very little things, I can't say the website is migrated, because I even haven't got the nodes, themes etc .. and I'm very confused with the current documentation

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Drush 9, you need to apply the patch from [Drush 9 port of commands](https://www.drupal.org/node/2914005) since Drush 9 is implementing drush commands in a new way. Otherwise downgrade to Drush 8.x.

If you're already using Drush 8.x, run:

```
drush en migrate_tools
drush cc drush
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `drush status` and `drush help` to see if Drush is working with your Drupal 8 site.  Presumably, `drush help` will confirm that the migrate-status command is not available.  Try enabling the migrate module on your Drupal 8 site.

Answer (score 1):

The drush support for Migrate isn't in core itself, but you can easily install it by installing the [Migrate Tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_tools) module. If you enable migrate_tools, you will get everything you need to use drush with your migrations:

```
$ drush en migrate_tools
The following extensions will be enabled: migrate_tools, migrate, migrate_plus
Do you really want to continue? (y/n): y
migrate was enabled successfully.                                                                                        [ok]
migrate_plus was enabled successfully.                                                                                   [ok]
migrate_tools was enabled successfully.                                                                                  [ok]
migrate_tools defines the following permissions: administer migrations 

$ drush help | grep migrate
All commands in migrate_tools: (migrate_tools)
 migrate-import (mi)   Perform one or more migration processes.
 migrate-manifest      Execute the migrations as specified in a manifest file.
 migrate-messages      View any messages associated with a migration.
 migrate-reset-status  Reset a active migration's status to idle.
 migrate-rollback      Rollback one or more migrations.
 migrate-status (ms)   List all migrations with current status.
 migrate-stop (mst)    Stop an active migration operation.
```

Comment: The [Migrate Tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_tools) module is a separate module, it's **not** included with Migrate Plus. Migrate Tools is required to support the "drush migrate-status" command.